# Angular 2 : not able to render json

Tags: angular

I am not able to render the following data in html and am getting an error. The console error is attach below the code. Currently I have single data in json, but it can be more in the future.

- processNo
- prodLine
- modelYear
- team_NO
- vmc

Please help as I am new to this. I tried referring similar questions, but it didn't work for me.

```js
/* json */

{
 "statuscode": 1,
 "message": "SUCESS",
 "template": null,
 "filter": {
  "controlNo": "25504",
  "processNo": "3A311",
  "plantCode": "T",
  "deptCode": "AF",
  "modelYear": "2017",
  "prodRate": "475",
  "prodLine": "3",
  "vmc": "A"
 }
}

/* controller */

constructor(private ReportServiceService:ReportServiceService) {   }

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.safetySummary();
  }

  safetySummary(){
    return this.ReportServiceService.getSafetySummary().subscribe(
      res => this.res = res.json())
  }
  
  
/* Error Msg in console */

compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("t Management - Process / Parts Summary</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid report-details" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let i in res.filter">
    <div class="row row-item">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-"): ng:///AppModule/ProcessPartSummaryComponent.html@166:46
Property binding ngForIn not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
      <div>Unit Management - Process / Parts Summary</div>
  </div>
  [ERROR ->]<div class="container-fluid report-details" *ngFor="let i in res.filter">
    <div class="row row-ite"): ng:///AppModule/ProcessPartSummaryComponent.html@166:2
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:36022:34)
    at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47134:19)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:61179:39)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:61099:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:61099:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:60986:19
    at Object.then (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:36012:148)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:60985:26)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:60914:37)
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid report-details" *ngFor="let i in res.filter">
    <div class="row row-item">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 report-detail-table">
          <span class="width-twenty bold">Process No.:</span>
          <span class="width-thirty">{{i.processNo}}</span>
          <span class="width-ten bold">Line:</span>
          <span class="width-forty">3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 report-detail-table">
          <span class="width-thirty bold">Model Cycle:</span>
          <span class="width-seventy">2017</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-item">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 report-detail-table">
          <span class="width-twenty bold">Team:</span>
          <span class="width-thirty">DL01</span>
          <span class="width-ten bold">VMC:</span>
          <span class="width-forty">3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 report-detail-table">
          <span class="width-thirty bold">Part Effective Date:</span>
          <span class="width-seventy">05/30/2017</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-item">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 report-detail-table">
          <span class="width-twenty bold">Process Name:</span>
          <span class="width-forty">RIGHT FRONT HARNESS INSTALL</span>
          <span class="width-forty"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 report-detail-table">
          <span class="width-thirty bold">Body/Line Loc:</span>
          <span class="width-seventy">D01R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let i in res.filter
```

should be

```
let i of res.filter
```

I've made this mistake multiple times.

Comment: thnks i am trying below and getting process number as blank ... its not even displaying console.log `safetySummary(){
    return this.ReportServiceService.getSafetySummary().subscribe(
      res => () => {
        this.filter = res.filter;
        this.processNo = res.filter.processNo;
        console.log("Process Number: "+this.processNo);
      })
  }`

Comment: Is getSafetySummary() using http service to get some data?  Also when you say console.log isn't displaying do you mean it's only displaying 'Process Number" or it's not even displaying 'Process Number' at all'?

Comment: i get data in res.filter.processNo  but not getting attach to this.processNo ... even console.log its not even printing text

Comment: i get proper response in service but not in component .... i changed my code to below and now i get it as undefined `ngOnInit() {  

    this.ReportServiceService.getSafetySummary().subscribe(
      res => this.res = res);

      console.log(this.res);
    
  }`

Comment: Probably easier to trouble shoot if you include your ReportService.getSafetySummary() code

Comment: `getSafetySummary(){
      return this.http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fl5iv')
               .map((res:Response) => res.json())
               .catch(this.getError);
  }

  private getError(error: Response):Observable<String>{
      return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server Issue');
  }`

Comment: i get proper response in res but it never get added to this.res = res

Comment: There are multiple errors in the code and I've put comments in the above working plunker to help you out.  Also you actually didn't even need to use *ngFor because that is used with arrays where you actually have it binding to an object.